# Unable to cross compile google-cloud-cpp using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, cmake, google-cloud-cpp

I'm unable to cross-compile `google-cloud-cpp` using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++. It seems to me that there's a bug in some protos files.

Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Steps

1. install `mingw-w64`
2. clone `google-cloud-cpp` with `v2.14.0` tag
3. run

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE=NEVER -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DGOOGLE_CLOUD_CPP_ENABLE=bigquery,storage -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/openssl_dir -Dnlohmann_json_DIR=/nlohmann_json -DCURL_LIBRARY=/curl/libcurl.a -DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/curl/include/ -DGOOGLE_CLOUD_CPP_ENABLE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace/cmake/toolchains/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake -DCrc32c_DIR=/Crc32c/ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Output

```
root@peeranat:/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build# make -j12
[  1%] Built target googleapis_download
[  1%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_config_change_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_consumer_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_backend_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_context_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_documentation_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_http_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_error_reason_protos
[  3%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_httpbody_protos
[  4%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_field_behavior_protos
[  4%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_launch_stage_protos
[  5%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_label_protos
[  8%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_common
[  8%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_routing_protos
[  8%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_source_info_protos
[  9%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_system_parameter_protos
[ 10%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_resource_protos
[  9%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_policy_protos
[ 10%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_visibility_protos
[ 10%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_orgpolicy_v1_orgpolicy_protos
[ 11%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_rpc_context_attribute_context_protos
[ 11%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_rpc_code_protos
[ 11%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_extended_operations_protos
[ 11%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_rpc_error_details_protos
[ 11%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_calendar_period_protos
[ 12%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_date_protos
[ 12%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_datetime_protos
[ 12%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_color_protos
[ 13%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_dayofweek_protos
[ 13%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_decimal_protos
[ 14%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_expr_protos
[ 14%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_localized_text_protos
[ 14%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_fraction_protos
[ 15%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_latlng_protos
[ 15%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_interval_protos
[ 16%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_money_protos
[ 17%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_postal_address_protos
[ 17%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_month_protos
[ 17%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_quaternion_protos
[ 17%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_phone_number_protos
[ 19%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_type_timeofday_protos
[ 19%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_metric_protos
[ 19%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_annotations_protos
[ 19%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_control_protos
[ 21%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_log_protos
[ 21%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_client_protos
[ 22%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_rpc_status_protos
[ 22%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_monitored_resource_protos
[ 24%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_devtools_source_v1_source_context_protos
[ 24%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_common_common_protos
[ 25%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_logging_type_type_protos
[ 25%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_auth_protos
[ 25%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_billing_protos
[ 26%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_distribution_protos
[ 27%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_endpoint_protos
[ 27%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_monitoring_protos
[ 28%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_usage_protos
[ 28%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_logging_protos
[ 28%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_quota_protos
[ 28%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_longrunning_operations_protos
[ 29%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_iam_v1_policy_protos
[ 29%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_iam_v1_options_protos
[ 30%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_devtools_cloudtrace_v2_trace_protos
[ 31%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_pubsub_protos
[ 32%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_api_service_protos
[ 36%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_rest_internal
[ 37%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_texttospeech_protos
[ 37%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_iam_v1_iam_policy_protos
[ 39%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_devtools_cloudtrace_v2_tracing_protos
[ 39%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_speech_protos
[ 41%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_logging_protos
[ 41%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_oauth2
[ 42%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_storage_protos
[ 46%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_bigtable_protos
[ 47%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_iam_protos
[ 56%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_spanner_protos
[ 59%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_dialogflow_v2_protos
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils
[ 66%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_cloud_bigquery_protos
[ 79%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_monitoring_protos
[ 88%] Built target google_cloud_cpp_storage
[ 88%] Building CXX object google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc.obj
[ 88%] Building CXX object google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc.obj
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc:16:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected identifier before '=' token
   54 |   OPTIONAL = 1,
      |            ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected '}' before '=' token
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:26: note: to match this '{'
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |                          ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
   54 |   OPTIONAL = 1,
      |            ^
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc:15:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected identifier before '=' token
   54 |   OPTIONAL = 1,
      |            ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected '}' before '=' token
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:26: note: to match this '{'
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |                          ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:54:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
   54 |   OPTIONAL = 1,
      |            ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:65:11: error: 'FieldBehavior' does not name a type
   65 | constexpr FieldBehavior FieldBehavior_MIN = FIELD_BEHAVIOR_UNSPECIFIED;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:65:11: error: 'FieldBehavior' does not name a type
   65 | constexpr FieldBehavior FieldBehavior_MIN = FIELD_BEHAVIOR_UNSPECIFIED;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:66:11: error: 'FieldBehavior' does not name a type
   66 | constexpr FieldBehavior FieldBehavior_MAX = NON_EMPTY_DEFAULT;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:66:11: error: 'FieldBehavior' does not name a type
   66 | constexpr FieldBehavior FieldBehavior_MAX = NON_EMPTY_DEFAULT;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:67:41: error: 'FieldBehavior_MAX' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'FieldBehavior_IsValid'?
   67 | constexpr int FieldBehavior_ARRAYSIZE = FieldBehavior_MAX + 1;
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         FieldBehavior_IsValid
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'const string& google::FieldBehavior_Name(T)':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:72:35: error: 'FieldBehavior' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'google::api::FieldBehavior'?
   72 |   static_assert(::std::is_same<T, FieldBehavior>::value ||
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                   google::api::FieldBehavior
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:6: note: 'google::api::FieldBehavior' declared here
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:72:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   72 |   static_assert(::std::is_same<T, FieldBehavior>::value ||
      |                                                ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: At global scope:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:79:53: error: 'FieldBehavior' has not been declared
   79 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::ConstStringParam name, FieldBehavior* value) {
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:67:41: error: 'FieldBehavior_MAX' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'FieldBehavior_IsValid'?
   67 | constexpr int FieldBehavior_ARRAYSIZE = FieldBehavior_MAX + 1;
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         FieldBehavior_IsValid
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'bool google::FieldBehavior_Parse(google::protobuf::ConstStringParam, int*)':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:80:60: error: 'FieldBehavior' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'google::api::FieldBehavior'?
   80 |   return ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseNamedEnum<FieldBehavior>(
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            google::api::FieldBehavior
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:6: note: 'google::api::FieldBehavior' declared here
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:81:44: error: no matching function for call to 'ParseNamedEnum<<expression error> >(const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*, const string&, int*&)'
   81 |     FieldBehavior_descriptor(), name, value);
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:46,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/rpc/status.pb.h:28,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/grpc_error_delegate.h:20,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/async_read_stream_impl.h:18,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/completion_queue.h:19,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.h:18,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc:15:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h:80:6: note: candidate: 'template<class EnumType> bool google::protobuf::internal::ParseNamedEnum(const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*, google::protobuf::ConstStringParam, EnumType*)'
   80 | bool ParseNamedEnum(const EnumDescriptor* descriptor, ConstStringParam name,
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h:80:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc:16:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:81:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   81 |     FieldBehavior_descriptor(), name, value);
      |                                            ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'const string& google::FieldBehavior_Name(T)':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:72:35: error: 'FieldBehavior' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'google::api::FieldBehavior'?
   72 |   static_assert(::std::is_same<T, FieldBehavior>::value ||
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                   google::api::FieldBehavior
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:6: note: 'google::api::FieldBehavior' declared here
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:72:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   72 |   static_assert(::std::is_same<T, FieldBehavior>::value ||
      |                                                ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: At global scope:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:79:53: error: 'FieldBehavior' has not been declared
   79 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::ConstStringParam name, FieldBehavior* value) {
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: At global scope:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:109: error: 'FieldBehavior_IsValid' is not a member of 'google::api'; did you mean 'google::FieldBehavior_IsValid'?
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:64:6: note: 'google::FieldBehavior_IsValid' declared here
   64 | bool FieldBehavior_IsValid(int value);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc:16:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:130: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                                                  ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:142: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                                                              ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:106:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
  106 | }  // namespace google
      | ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'bool google::FieldBehavior_Parse(google::protobuf::ConstStringParam, int*)':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:80:60: error: 'FieldBehavior' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'google::api::FieldBehavior'?
   80 |   return ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::ParseNamedEnum<FieldBehavior>(
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            google::api::FieldBehavior
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:52:6: note: 'google::api::FieldBehavior' declared here
   52 | enum FieldBehavior : int {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:81:44: error: no matching function for call to 'ParseNamedEnum<<expression error> >(const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*, const string&, int*&)'
   81 |     FieldBehavior_descriptor(), name, value);
      |                                            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:46,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/rpc/status.pb.h:28,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/grpc_error_delegate.h:20,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/async_read_stream_impl.h:18,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/completion_queue.h:19,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:18,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc:15:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h:80:6: note: candidate: 'template<class EnumType> bool google::protobuf::internal::ParseNamedEnum(const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor*, google::protobuf::ConstStringParam, EnumType*)'
   80 | bool ParseNamedEnum(const EnumDescriptor* descriptor, ConstStringParam name,
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_enum_reflection.h:80:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc:15:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:81:44: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   81 |     FieldBehavior_descriptor(), name, value);
      |                                            ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor* google::protobuf::GetEnumDescriptor() [with E = google::api::FieldBehavior]':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:113:25: error: 'FieldBehavior_descriptor' is not a member of 'google::api'; did you mean 'google::FieldBehavior_descriptor'?
  113 |   return ::google::api::FieldBehavior_descriptor();
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc:16:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:69:48: note: 'google::FieldBehavior_descriptor' declared here
   69 | const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::EnumDescriptor* FieldBehavior_descriptor();
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: At global scope:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:109: error: 'FieldBehavior_IsValid' is not a member of 'google::api'; did you mean 'google::FieldBehavior_IsValid'?
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:64:6: note: 'google::FieldBehavior_IsValid' declared here
   64 | bool FieldBehavior_IsValid(int value);
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc:15:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:130: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                                                  ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:90:142: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   90 |     ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::RepeatedEnumTypeTraits< ::google::api::FieldBehavior, ::google::api::FieldBehavior_IsValid>, 14, true >
      |                                                                                                                                              ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:106:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
  106 | }  // namespace google
      | ^
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h: In function 'const google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor* google::protobuf::GetEnumDescriptor() [with E = google::api::FieldBehavior]':
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:113:25: error: 'FieldBehavior_descriptor' is not a member of 'google::api'; did you mean 'google::FieldBehavior_descriptor'?
  113 |   return ::google::api::FieldBehavior_descriptor();
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/common.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.pb.h:33,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/iam/credentials/v1/iamcredentials.grpc.pb.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.h:22,
                 from /workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/google/cloud/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc:15:
/workspace/deps/google-cloud-cpp/build/external/googleapis/google/api/field_behavior.pb.h:69:48: note: 'google::FieldBehavior_descriptor' declared here
   69 | const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::EnumDescriptor* FieldBehavior_descriptor();
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/build.make:287: google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/internal/grpc_impersonate_service_account.cc.obj] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/build.make:347: google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/internal/minimal_iam_credentials_stub.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2770: google/cloud/CMakeFiles/google_cloud_cpp_grpc_utils.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Comment: The error at `OPTIONAL = 1,` looks like something defines `OPTIONAL` as a macro (`windows.h` perhaps?).

Comment: Right `ntdef.h` defines IN, OUT, OPTIONAL, NOTHING, CRITICAL, and about 900 other names.  :-(  Including really "useful" ones like `#define CONST const`

Comment: ahh thanks. but how do you know it's due to a `macro`?

Comment: A meaningless error points right after an all-caps identifier, and all-caps is commonly used for macros, and Windows is known for defining a bunch of crap macros.

Comment: If you are trying to cross-compile for Windows on Linux, you will need the Windows SDK. That includes the Windows header files, library imports, and DLLs.